# Sending of url to confirm user registration in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a site in asp.net mvc 2.0 .Here i want to send the url link to the user email on user registration.I want to send the url format in such a way that if user clicks on that link it will take him to the index page of user module where he can enter his user name and password and login to the user module.

Please tell me how to do it or give me the links of these type of posts.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why take the user to the login page?  If they have that link, they are the authenticated user, so why not just take them to a confirmation page and automatically log them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [UrlHelper.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult Email()
{
    // Notice the last parameter which contains the protocol:
    // this one is important if you want the helper to generate
    // an absolute url. If you don't specify this parameter the
    // generated url will be relative
    string url = Url.Action("index", "home", null, "http");

    // TODO: Send url by email
    _repository.SendMail(url);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hey Darin thanks for your response.I am trying the things.please send me any link of this type of post.Because i am unable to initialise the UrlHelper class using RequestContext .So how to initialise this class .Is there any post regarding this.

Comment: In which part of your application you need to use `UrlHelper`? It is accessible only in the controller and views. Instantiating it in other parts of the application might not be a good idea.

Comment: Models shouldn't generate urls as urls are specific to the web while models should be more generic. I would recommend you doing the url generation in the controller and pass it to the model.

Comment: System.Net.Mail.MailAddress fromAddress=new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("dflanagan01@earthlink.net");
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress toAddress=new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(e.EventManagerEMail);
                    UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper();
                    string url=Url.Action("Index", "EventAdmin", null, "http");
                    
                    string mailStatus=Stalbans.Models.MailRepository.SendEmail(fromAddress,toAddress, "Registeration Details", "UserName:"+e.EventManagerEMail+" Password:"+password);

Comment: @Mallikarjuna, generate the url in the controller and pass it as argument to the method sending the email.

Comment: I can't initialise the UrlHelper class.                       UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext);
string url=Url.Action("Index", "EventAdmin", null, "http"); But here it is showing error in HttpContext .